# Prove this theorem from linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Theorem: If $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ such that each $e_j$ is an eigenvector, then the matrix of $A$ with respect to this basis is diagonal,
and the diagonal elements are precisely the eigenvalues.

Please prove in simple terms as I am not very experienced with linear algebra.

Comment: A more general statement is valid: If a basis of a vector space consists of eigenvectors of a linear operator $A$, then in this basis the matrix of this operator has a diagonal form. 

This statement immediately follows from the definition of the matrix of a linear operator.

All other conditions are superfluous.

Comment: The result is pretty much immediate. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: The book I am studying linear algebra from, just wrote this statement and didn;t give a proof. I don't understand why these diagonal elements are eigenvalues.

Comment: Take any $e_j$, multiply it by $A$, and equate this to $\lambda_j e_j$, where $\lambda_j$ is the eigenvalue associated to eigenvector $e_j$. Put everything on the left of the equal sign, that makes a linear combination of $e_i$s that is equal to $0$. As the $e_i$s form a basis, this implies all coefficients of $e_i$s on this expression are null. You get that the non-diagonal elements of $A$ on column $j$ are null, and the diagonal one is equal to $\lambda_j$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Thanks. Please write this as an answer, and I will accept it as a solution so that this question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **simplest proof**:
$\forall e_j, A e_j = \lambda_j e_j$, where $\lambda_j$ is the eigenvalue.
In any basis $B$ which includes $e_j$ as $k$-th basis vector, the $k$-th column of $A$ in basis $B$ is $A e_j$. So $A e_j$ is composed of $\lambda_j$ on the diagonal and zeroes everywhere else. And that's all.

So if $B$ is entirely made of eigenvectors, $A$ is diagonal and has on its diagonal the eigenvalues.
But if $B$ contains non-eigenvectors, columns of $A$ corresponding to eigenvectors are still entirely zeroes, except the diagonal elements which are the eigenvalues.
This proof implicitely uses the fact that a basis is an independent set of vectors: a matrix has a unique representation in this basis, and from $A e_j = \lambda_j e_j$ we directly get the corresponding column of $A$.

If we want to make explicit this use of the independence property, this is the **proof stated in the comments**:
Basis $B = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$. Let $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1\dots n}$ in this basis.
In basis $B$, $e_j$ is only zeroes, except a $1$ on the $j$-th element.
Then $A e_j$ in basis $B$ is the $j$-th column of $A$ in this basis: $A e_j = \sum_{i=1 \dots n} a_{ij} e_i$.
But also $A e_j = \lambda_j e_j$.
So $a_{0j} e_0 + a_{1j} e_1 + \dots + (a_{jj} - \lambda_j) e_j + \dots + a_{nj} e_n = 0$.
This is a linear combination of independent vectors equal to zero: it implies each coefficient is null.
So we get $a_{ij} = 0$ when $i \ne j$, and $a_{jj} = \lambda_j$.